# Entities in 'Y' participate in the 'FK_Y_X' relationship. 0 related 'X' were found. 1 'X' is expected

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6

I have a `1..*` relationship between `X` and `Y`, where `X` is the parent. When I try and delete record `Y` I get the following exception message:

> Entities in 'Y' participate in the 'FK_Y_X' relationship. 0 related 'X' were found. 1 'X' is expected.

I am currently trying to delete the record in a generic, disconnected manner in the following way:

```
public bool Delete(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The entity that is passed in is loaded with `AsNoTracking()` on the same context.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityState.Deleted does not work, Remove(entity) does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194162/entitystate-deleted-does-not-work-removeentity-does) - not an exact one, but perhaps it explains your problem well enough

Comment: @BartoszKP The entity `Y` is a child and has no further children. Calling `Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity)` results in the same once attached. To confirm, I want to only delete record `Y`, I am not interested in `X` at all so `X` was not loaded.

Comment: Do you have the constraint on the child instead of parent?

Answer (score 5):

Try to add a public property YId to X which will hold the connection to Y,
this solved my issue, i use Breeze with EF6 and i've got the same error.

```
Class Y 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<X> Xs { get; set; }
}

Class X 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int YId { get; set; }   
    public Y Y { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you `context.Y.Attach(x);` make sure that the object `x` holds the "Id" to the parent entity. You need both.

Example:

```
x.Id = 3;
x.ParentEntity.Id = 10;
```

That solved my problem at least. I forgot the parent id in the object which i attached.

Comment: if you don't mind, will you extend this answer to explain that, in general, this problem occurs when lazy loading is disabled and that you should call `context.y.Attach(x)` if you have not already? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to allow NULL values on the parent entity (X) or remove the entity if you are not going to use it anymore

Answer (score 0):

For me my record in my database had a NULL value for the FK column in question. I populated that column with a valid value and the record was able to be removed via EF Remove method.