# Entity Framework deletion does not work as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

There are two tables in my SQL Server 2012 database. One is individual, the second is company. Company has a column called finance manager which is a nullable column, and referencing individual. This relationship is not cascade delete.

When I try to delete individual.

Expected behavior:

if individual is being referenced as finance manager in company, EF should through an error that the record is being referenced

Actual behavior:

EF puts null into finance manager field of the company and deletes the individual

How can I achieve expected behavior?

Code:

```
    entities.Individuals.DeleteObject(individual);
    entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityState.Deleted does not work, Remove(entity) does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194162/entitystate-deleted-does-not-work-removeentity-does)

Comment: Yep. That does seem to be [what it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete): "If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable, Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null."

Comment: but it is db first approach. can you guyz please suggest me any solution?

Comment: Then change your FK from Company to Individual to `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

Comment: it is already set to no action